# Unknown column in field list when using SUM(something) AS a

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using following query for getting sum of 2 columns from a table

```
SELECT a.user, b.user, SUM(a.post = b.post) AS common_p_count,
SUM(a.option = b.option) AS common_r_count,
(common_p_count+common_r_count)
FROM response a, response b
WHERE a.user = '1' AND b.user != '1' group by b.user
```

But i am getting **Unknown column common_p_count**

How can i use common_p_count and common_r_count in this query for ordering result?

Thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY common_p_count+common_r_count` ...?

Comment: I don't think this query does anything useful.  Consider asking *another* question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot select a column that you've defined on the same level in your `SELECT` clause. If you want to reuse an expression, you have to resort to using a derived table:

```
SELECT x.*, (common_p_count+common_r_count)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.user AS a_user, 
    b.user AS b_user, 
    SUM(a.post = b.post) AS common_p_count,
    SUM(a.option = b.option) AS common_r_count
  FROM response a, response b
  WHERE a.user = '1' AND b.user != '1' group by b.user
) x
```

Or, of course, you simply repeat the expression:

```
SELECT 
  a.user AS a_user, 
  b.user AS b_user, 
  SUM(a.post = b.post) AS common_p_count,
  SUM(a.option = b.option) AS common_r_count,
  (SUM(a.post = b.post) + SUM(a.option = b.option))
FROM response a, response b
WHERE a.user = '1' AND b.user != '1' group by b.user
```

If you just want to order by that expression, then that's possible without any tricks (but you still cannot `SELECT` the expression on the same level of your query)

```
SELECT 
  a.user AS a_user, 
  b.user AS b_user, 
  SUM(a.post = b.post) AS common_p_count,
  SUM(a.option = b.option) AS common_r_count
FROM response a, response b
WHERE a.user = '1' AND b.user != '1' group by b.user
ORDER BY common_p_count + common_r_count
```

[The reason for this is explained in this blog article here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/)

#### Side-note

Apart from the above explanations, of course, I don't think your query is correct. Since you're grouping only by `b.user`, you'll get a random value for `a.user` and probably your sums are incorrect as well as you get an accidental cartesian product, in my opinion. But that's a topic for another question.